# How can i redirect my url to specific page when user access admin

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

1.i want to redirect my site to mysite.com/control/index.php panel if url having  mysite.com/admin using htaccess. can any one help on this? 
This is my htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a new rule to handle `/admin` URI:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^admin(/.*)?$ control/index.php$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: it is  working in my local for my htaccess but did not work in live sever

Comment: If it worked for me and is working on your localhost that means rules are correct. I cannot guess what's wrong on your live server without full details about live server setup.